# Polarization of Light Without Reducing Intensity

Tags: optics

I think I have figured out a way to polarized light with negligible intensity loss using polarizing beam splitters and laser beam combiners. I am just wondering if there is any practical application for such a discovery.

Answer (score 3):

Polarizing an unpolarized beam, without reducing the intensity or increasing the etendue, would violate the second law of thermodynamics.

So what's the practical application? It's good pedagogy. You can think more carefully about how your scheme would work, eventually realize that it actually doesn't work after all, and in the process you will come to understand physics a little bit better and even have fun. :-P

Comment: Polarizer acting as beamsplitter to separate two orthogonal polarizations, then realign one polarization with another using some quarter-wave plate, then merge the beams back together (which is the not-doable-perfectly etendue-increasing step, right?).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!

Comment: What if you do not realign the polarizations? Then could you not use coherent polarization beam combining to recombine the orthogonally polarized beams and get a polarized beam?

Comment: If you combine a horizontally and vertically polarized beam using a beamsplitter, you can with linear polarization, or circular ... or unpolarized! How do you propose to avoid winding up in the same unpolarized situation you started in?

Comment: The idea proposed by LLIAMnYP is actually doable and there have been filters that have been produced on this idea. The filters, proposed in this paper https://www.osapublishing.org/optica/fulltext.cfm?uri=optica-1-5-356&id=304825, transmit about 70% of light.

Comment: I don't get that paper. If the two polarizations get sent to the same direction, then it violates thermodynamics and the paper is wrong. If they get sent to different directions, why not just use a beamsplitter cube and a half-wave-plate and some mirrors to accomplish the same thing with >99% efficiency? I don't see a clear discussion of this in the paper.